# Nuxt.js Layout not being added to routes

Tags: vue.js, layout, nuxt.js

I'm trying to apply my layout on other pages but it's not added.
it's working fine on `IndexPage` but it's not in other routers
I have my layout file on `layouts/publicLayout.vue`

```html
<template lang="pug">
    .layout(class="overflow-x-hidden")
        NavBarMobileNavBar.relative.z-50(v-if="isMobile")
        NavBar(v-else)
        Nuxt
        Footer
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
@Component({
  name: 'publicLayout'
})
```

here is the `IndexPage` code where the layout is applied:

```html
<template lang="pug">
main.bg-gray-50
  section#hero.w-full.flex
 html/pug code...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
@Component({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  layout: 'publicLayout'
})
```

I did the same as always on another page called `/services` but's it's not applied it all:

```html
<template lang="pug">
    .w-full.h-96.bg-red-400.text-center
        h1 Services
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
@Component({
  layout: 'publicLayout'
})
```

when I opened the Devtools it shows me this: `.nuxtLayoutDefault.vue`

[image]

instead of : `PublicLayout`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's working.
I just noticed that I didn't close the `</scrpit>` tag on `/services` page

Comment: Now it's working? Try to use ESlint, it may give you such informations when you forget something or alike.